# does myeclipse require any server configuration?

Tags: myeclipse

i'm new to myeclipse. There is no option like dynamic web project in myeclipse. How to run web projects here? doesn't it require any server configurations like tomcat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MyEclipse there are a lot of predefined servers, and also two integrated sandboxes:

- one for database: Derby
- one for web server: Tomcat

To modify these settings, go to `Window/Preferences/MyEclipse/Servers` 
The integrated server configurations are enabled by default, and when you create a web application, the inline tomcat's libraries and classes are used.

However, if you have your own tomcat / other web server set up somewhere on your machine, you can simply disable the one in integrated sandbox, and configure the one you'd like to use.

The screenshot below might help a bit:
[image: myeclipse server setup]